# Is Akdomus a Dvor Shebikedushah which would require a minyan to read it?

Tags: torah-reading, shavuos

There are communities which still are in lock-down and will be unable to have a minyan on Shavuos. Members of  some of these communities, will read the Torah portion at home.

My question asks first if Akdomus is [a Dvor Shebikedushah](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94_%D7%9B%D7%92_%D7%91) something that requires a minyan and therefore cannot be read by the individual?

If it is not a Dvor Shebikedushah and the  individual may say it, is it a good idea for  the  individual to  say it?

Comment: I'm a little supposed by this question. Why might you think it's a davar shebikdusha? Is there any reason to think it's obligatory at all and not just a custom? Are any customs davar shebikdusha?

Comment: @DoubleAA The Rav thought Anim Zemirot could be a davar shebikedusha https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/951536/rabbi-hershel-schachter/piskei-corona-24-anim-zmiros-without-a-minyan/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per letter from Rabbi Hershel Schachter dated 26 Iyar 5780, although the Minhag is only to say it B'Tzibur, it is similar to a Shabbos songs such as Ko Ribon that one may say without a Minyan. [image]

Answer (score 3):

In this past week's [GSEM](https://images.shulcloud.com/288/uploads/Weekly%20Bulletins/GSEMBamidbar20.pdf), R' Mantel at KAJ said that Akdamut may be said and that further, one should read the 'Aseret haDibrot in ta'am 'elyon.

Comment: GSEM? (15 char)

Comment: @JoelK, the weekly pre-Shabbos bulletin. As it is referred to by its acronym, I used that as the title